# Query regarding $(x^2 + αy^2 + β) (y^2 – xy – 2x^2) = 0$

Tags: conic-sections

The equation $(x^2 + αy^2 + β) (y^2 – xy – 2x^2) = 0$ always represents

(A) A circle and a pair of straight lines if α = 1 and β = 0

(B) A pair of straight line and an ellipse if α ≠ 1 and α > 0

(C) A pair of hyperbolas if α < 0

(D) A pair of straight lines and a hyperbola if α < 0 and β ≠ 0

My approach $(y^2 – xy – 2x^2)=0$ represent a pair of straight line the lines are $y-2x=0$ & $y+x=0$ , 
Hence Choice C gets eliminated as pair of straight line option is not there.

$(x^2 + αy^2 + β)  = 0$ case, if α = 1 and β = 0 it is a case of a point in lieu of circle hence A is also eliminated

$(x^2 + αy^2 + β)  = 0$ case, if α ≠ 1 and α > 0 it can be an ellipse but not sure about the value of "β".

$(x^2 + αy^2 + β)  = 0$ case, if β ≠ 0 and α <0 it is a case of hyperbola

My query is regarding choice (B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(x^2 + αy^2 + β)  = 0$, if α ≠ 1 and α > 0, β must be negative for it to be an ellipse. So, it is not always true and (B) is not the answer.

For $(x^2 + αy^2 + β) = 0$, sine β ≠ 0 and α <0, it can always be cast in a standard hyperbola form, either with major axis along x or y depending on the sign of β. Therefore, (D) should be the choice.